# In Node.js, which queues are executed untill they are empty, and which are not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, queue, backend

So, I know that when JavaScript runs in a browser there are a few event queues, like the micro and macro task queue. I know that in the case of the former its content is always entirely executed until it's empty, while in the case of the macro task queue, only the first task is executed per loop cycle.

Now, I'm totally new to Node.js and I was trying to grasp how the event loop works. I have not been able to find this kind of information (how many elements of a queue are executed to completion during every cycle) with regards to the queues and loop phases that Node.js uses.

I would appreciate if you could shed some light over this.